# Launch iOS application using URL

Tags: ios, nsurl

I'm trying to launch my iOS application from other application say for eg: mail or browser (any browser not only safari) with params. I've googled and found we can use URL scheme but it works only with safari browser, how do I replicate the same behaviour with other applications(eg: chrome).

Note: Basically I'm sharing a some song through email, that user should able to open that song with my application. Hopes clears.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: URL schemes work in all apps. Can you let us know why you think they're specific to Safari? Then we'll be able to help with whatever the real problem is.

Comment: I tried to open url like "myapp://" in safari.. It opens my app. However in chrome it doesn't. Do you have any idea?

Comment: That means Chrome is broken. At the iOS level, your app will receive any URL for which it is registered that is passed to `UIApplication -openURL:`. Apps that are properly written will ask `UIApplication` whether it can handle URLs they can't and pass them off appropriately. That includes all the built-in apps (Safari, Mail, etc) and most third-party apps. Obviously Google has other priorities.

Comment: Do I need to do anything specific for chrome. But that doesn't make sense as user can open his mail from any browser. Then Is there any way to handle this problem?

Comment: You may be confusing two completely different things here. 1) Your app could define a custom URL scheme. Then tapping a link (in Mobile Safari, Mail, or other apps) would launch your app. 2) You can setup your app to declare that the app can open certain types of files. Then the app appears as an option when trying to open that type of file such as when viewing an email attachment in Mail. Which do you want?

Comment: First one... And one more thing as Tommy mentioned, with other browser like safari, fox it is launching my app once the url clicked... but not with chrome.

Answer (score 2):

To have other apps launch your app, you need to implement a custom URL scheme. Look at the **Implementing Custom URL Schemes** section of [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50).

Answer (score 0):

Problem with chrome is It start searching whatever we types until unless it is a proper link. when you type, it shows some suggestion down in which one is link that works as expected. Anyhow thank you guys.